# How to Wait for Parallel Sidekiq Workers to All Complete Before Calling Another Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidetiq

I have several workers that are being run using Sidekiq and scheduled using Sidetiq.  I'm looking for advice on the best way to wait for all workers to complete before executing a callback, similar to Sidekiq-Pro's batching functionality. Any advice on possible options would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately the best way I have found is to "know" how many jobs are in a batch, and then keep a count when they complete (or error).

Comment: There's a reason I charge money for that feature: it's extremely useful and at the same time extremely difficult to build.  I assume you have no budget?

Comment: It's a step that I think we will ultimately be working toward, but until our ETL process is more fleshed out and we are reading in more data sources / using more workers, it isn't 100% necessary at this stage.  It is certainly something on our radar, but at this point, I'm just looking for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a method:

```
def wait_for_sidekiq
  sleep(1) until Sidekiq::Workers.new.size == 0 && Sidekiq::Queue.new.size == 0
end
```

I would also suggest that you make sure that the jobs got queued in the first place:

```
def wait_for_queuing
  sleep(1) until Sidekiq::Queue.new.size > 0 || Sidekiq::Workers.new.size > 0
end
```

This is required, because sometimes the first method might get executed a few miliseconds before queuing the jobs, so that it won't wait at all.

Answer (score 3):

For simple use cases you can poll [stats](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#stats) to get a count of pending jobs for each queue.

So if you know that all your jobs go to a specific queue, and there are no other jobs going in that queue from elsewhere this would suffice. For more advanced/complex use cases you can refer the [API source](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/api.rb)

Another simple solution is to use a [Redis](http://redis.io) based counter (since you are already using Redis) and [atomically decrement](http://redis.io/commands/decr) it from each job, and [publish](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) an event once the count reaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

You should see this [Sidekiq-batch gem](https://github.com/breamware/sidekiq-batch), i already try it and it works just like the Sidekiq's Pro Batch, and it's **free**

Hope this could help